# CloudFront POST / PUT at Edge. object invalidation propagation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Having a CloudFront distribution with a S3 bucket as origin, after a file is updated on that bucket it won't get invalidated on all CF Edges until either the TLL has passed (default is 24h) or you invalidate it manually.

But instead of updating the file directly on S3, I can also [PUT/POST the file through a CF Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-content-uploads-post-put-other-methods/) and let it send it back to my origin (the S3 bucket).

My question is, when sending the file through a CF Edge, does the rest of the Edges invalidate their old file immediately too? I know the one I've just send it through is updated, but what about the rest?

Comment: *"I know the one I've just send it through is updated"*  How do you know this? I've never seen this documented anywhere.

Comment: Because I tested it, I couldn't find any doc either

Comment: What you observed also could reflect a flaw in your test methodology.

Comment: That's true, this is what I did (my files are private): Create a signed cookie. Upload an updated file using it. Create a different signed cookie and generate a URL with it (also tried with the same signature). Use the new signed URL to fetch the file somewhere else. The file come up at it latest version. I've just even tried through a VPN and still get it updated. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it looks like by default Cache-Control: no-cache was being sent. So it looks like the answer is no invalidation occurs whatsoever :(